# Create two different outputs from the same file in webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, build, create-react-app

I need to change the build process of my react application, so that it creates two different outputs of the same file. At this time it only creates a `index.js` which is minified but i want another output which is basically the same as the `index.js` but gziped.

Is it possible to change the webpack config to get 2 files (one minified and the other gziped) from the same `entry` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the `Webpack` config of an app built with `create-react-app` you have to `eject` the app, then write your own `Webpack` config files.. This can be extremely painful, and essentially nullifies (one of) the biggest reasons to use `create-react-app`..

I think it would be easiest to write a script that does the gzipping for you, after the build is finished.

I put this together real quick to show how you can `gzip` a file with command line arguments...

**How to use:** `node gzipper.js %SOURCE_FILE_PATH% %DEST_DIR_PATH%`

- ex: `node gzipper.js ./build/index.js ./build`
- Supports relative paths and absolute paths.
- Uses 'standard libraries' - requires no additional packages

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const SOURCE = path.resolve(__dirname, process.argv[2]);
const DESTINATION = path.resolve(__dirname, process.argv[3]);

const SOURCE_STATS = fs.lstatSync(SOURCE);
const SOURCE_FILE_NAME = path.basename(SOURCE);
const DESTINATION_STATS = fs.lstatSync(DESTINATION);

if(!SOURCE_STATS.isFile() || !DESTINATION_STATS.isDirectory()) {
    throw new Error("[ERROR]::SOURCE must be a file, DESTINATION must be a directory!");
}

const SOURCE_CONTENTS = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(SOURCE, 'utf8'));

zlib.gzip(SOURCE_CONTENTS, (error, result) => {
    if(error) throw error;

    const OUT_PATH = `${DESTINATION}\\${SOURCE_FILE_NAME}.gz`;
    fs.writeFileSync(OUT_PATH, result);
});
```

You could add a script to your `package.json` file, something like `gzip` that you add onto the `npm build` (or `yarn build`) script, so it runs after build..:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && npm run gzip",
    "gzip": "node gzipper.js ./build/index.js ./build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```